# Add a class or id to a one line Ruby 'if else' statement in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I was wondering that can I add a class of id to a one line Ruby 'if else' statement?

For example adding class:"glyphicon glyphicon-ok" to this:

```
<%= @example.completed? ? ' Incomplete' : ' Complete' %>
```

EDIT: Sorry for being unclear.

I know how I can add a class to an if statement in Rails, like:

```
<div>
  <% if @example.count == 0 %>
       <p class="red">Hello</p>
  <% else %>
       <p class="blue">Text here</p>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

But if I make it in one line, it's something like the following? But how do I add a class to that line? Just trying to learn.

```
<%= (idea.count == 0) ? 'Hello' : 'Text here' %>
```

Comment: and what's the question?

Comment: I can't see how what you appear to be asking relates to the code fragment.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer - Most likely it is `<div class="<%= @example.completed? ? ' Incomplete' : ' Complete' %>">`, Still it is unclear what is the question.

Comment: Ah, I see what he might be asking.  Let's take a stab at an answer. :)

Comment: It will be much more readable if you don't do this in one line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just inline your example.

```
<div>
   <p class="blue"><%= idea.count == 0 ? 'Hello' : 'Text here' %></p>
</div>
```

Please note that your code also was setting a different class. That would force you to write

```
<div>
   <p class="<%= idea.count == 0 ? 'red' : 'blue' %>"><%= idea.count == 0 ? 'Hello' : 'Text here' %></p>
</div>
```

Which is a very convoluted code. In the case of the example, the standard if-condition is the cleanest approach.

Answer (score 3):

Probably the cleanest way is not to use pure html in your template:

```
<%= content_tag :div, class: @example.completed? ? ' Incomplete' : ' Complete' do %>
  // inner content
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're trying to set the CSS class ID with a ternary operator:

```
<div class='glyphicon<%= @example.ok? "-ok" : "" %>'>
```